# firebase realtime does not work on phone but its working on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btSave.setOnClickListener {
            val firstName = binding.etFirstName.text.toString()
            val lastName = binding.etLastName.text.toString()
            val age = binding.etAge.text.toString()
            val userName = binding.etUserName.text.toString()

            if (firstName.isNotEmpty() && age.isNotEmpty() && lastName.isNotEmpty() && userName.isNotEmpty()) {

                database =
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .getReference("Users")

                val users = User(firstName, lastName, age, userName)

                database.child(userName).setValue(users).addOnSuccessListener {

     
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

and I give internet access to the project what should I do now ??
but app is working for Auth !

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @

Comment: @AlexMamo the code is correct and it does not have error but it just does not work on the phone by the way I connect to google firebase from Iran